# What am i missing regarding return?

Tags: python, function, inheritance, return

I am new to programming, and I stumbled over the same phenomenon several times. Maybe I am stupid, but I don't understand why sometimes I can write working def functions with return statements, and "inheritance"(?) of the values works just fine, and sometimes not.

Here is the recent example where it doesn't work, and i don't know why:

import sys

file_1 = sys.argv[1]

file_2 = sys.argv[2]

text_1 = []

text_2 = []

def reading(file_1, file_2):

```
for line_1 in file_1:
    line_2 = file_2.readline()
    text_1.append(line_1)
    text_2.append(line_2)
return text_1, text_2
```

file_1 = open(file_1, 'r')

file_2 = open(file_2, 'r')

text_1, text_2 = reading(file_1, file_2)

print(text_1)

print(text_2)

file_1.close()

file_2.close()

Comment: What do you mean *"inheritance"(?) of the values* and what is the problem you want help with?

Comment: By inheritance I mean the transfer from the reading()-local space variables line_1 and line_2 to the print(line_1) and line_2.statement in like global space. I would like to know why in this example python responses with NameError at line 20, which is the first print statement: line_1 is not defined.

Comment: Your loop doesn't look right. You're asking to loop through all lines but only do a thing to one. You're return is also not properly indented. Right now, it's attempting to return "within' the loop but it should return "outside" the loop and inside the function

Comment: I edited, hope it makes more sense now, although I'm not completely sure about it's correctness and open for improvement advice. 
Since I was just curious about the return issue, I did not check on how much sense code as a whole makes... whats still strange: in the end of text_2, I get lots of ['', '', ''] empty strings. Can you see why? They are not there in the input files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of your `reading` function, like so `line_1, line_2 = reading(file_1, file_2)`. `line_1` and `line_2` are private to your `reading` function.

Comment: thank you very much, I wasn't aware that return does not automatically "return to global"... Precious info to me. thx!